# Как зашифровать данные в wav файл?

Tags: python, node.js, wav

Всем доброго времени суток. Уперся в непонятную на данный момент задачу.

Резко стало необходимым передать байты (биты) с помощью звука. Используется схема bluetooth передатчик и bluetooth приемник. (Не микрофон - динамики).

Смотрел в FFT, но что-то ничего не смог придумать как закодировать байты опираясь на частоту волны.

Натолкните пожалуйста на решение. Заранее спасибо

Comment: 0x00 - 220Гц, 0хFF - 7040Гц, все что между - распределить по желанию. Частоты тоже можно взять по желанию в другие. Здесь для простоты иллюстрации использованы ля малой и пятой октав.

Comment: @Эникейщик, спасибо. А не подскажите библиотеку которая на вход принимает wav 16 bit 44100 Sample Rate и 2 канала и кодирует (или раскодирует данные). Генерация wav потока уже с нужной частотой для расшифровки на приемной стороне. Есть такие?